# How do I upload a java script object containing large files to my backend node server using axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, axios, http-post

I was trying to do a post request to a backend node server using axios on react. But got a 404 error for the file being too larg for axios to make the transfer.

const handleSubmit = async () => {

```
    let formObj = null;
    // create a form element 
    formObj = new FormData();
    if(formObj){
        // make the data iterable
        let frmCollection = Object.entries(formData);
        // append the data to form data object
        frmCollection.forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => formObj.append(fieldName, fieldValue));
        

        try{     
            const postReq = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/postData', formData);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    } else{
        console.log('form not valid');
    }
}
```

I did this
const handleSubmit = async () => {

```
    let formObj = null;
    // create a form element 
    formObj = new FormData();
    if(formObj){
        // make the data iterable
        let frmCollection = Object.entries(formData);
        // append the data to form data object
        frmCollection.forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => formObj.append(fieldName, fieldValue));
        

        try{     
            const postReq = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/postData', formData);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    } else{
        console.log('form not valid');
    }
}
```

and I was expecting some positive response from the back end instead i got the following error:

[axios 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKxHP.png)

Comment: It seems your request isn't able to find the route '/postData'. It could be due to the backend server is not running or the path is not properly added to the routing. Check this [link](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example), how to post multipart data.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, in order to send data to backend server, we must set a header like
{ headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
And I think that you just couldn't do that with pure axios